# Remove list element where any of the row sums in the element are less than a certain value (in R)

Tags: r, list, filtering

Apologies in advance for what I know is simple. I just haven't been able to find the solution despite the 1000 search attempts and my rudimentary skills are not up to the challenge.

I have a list of matrices consisting of rows of integers. I can find row totals etc with (l)apply function etc. What I am stuck on however is removing an entire element if any of the rows fail a certain criteria, say a total of <500.

So in the below example:

```
x1 <- rnorm(50,5,0.32)
dim(x1) <- c(5,10)
x2 =rnorm(50,25,3.2)
dim(x2) <- c(5,10)
x3 =rnorm(50,25,3.2)
dim(x3) <- c(5,10)
x4=rnorm(50,0.8,0.1)
dim(x4) <- c(5,10)
x5=rep(NaN,50)
dim(x5) <- c(5,10)

list1<-list(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

If I sum each row in each element for a total:

```
goodbit <- lapply(list1, function (x) apply(x, 1, function(c) sum(c)))
```

I know I can filter out the elements with NAs:

```
list1nonas  <- Filter(Negate(anyNA),list1)
```

But I am having a hard time extending that to criteria based on the row totals. For example how can I remove any element where any row total in that element is < 8.
(Element [[4]] in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`. If we want to test whether there are any `rowSums` less than 8 in a given matrix `x`, we can do `any(rowSums(x) < 8)`. Therefore the logical negation negation of this will return `TRUE` if none of the row sums are less than 8.

We can therefore put this inside an `sapply` to run the test on each matrix in our list, and return a logical vector.

Subsetting our original list by this vector returns a filtered list with only those matrices that have no row sums below 8.

```r
list1[sapply(list1, function(x) !any(rowSums(x) < 8))]
```

Comment: Or with `Filter` `Filter(\(x) all(rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) >= 8), list1)`